# How to link Google Play Console & Google Cloud project with different accounts

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-play-console

Title says everything: Can/How can I link my Google Play Console account with my Google Cloud account if both are not running under the same login i.e:

play console using `abc@gmail.com` and google cloud using `def@gmail.com`

I found the same question with no answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68213532/can-i-link-google-cloud-project-and-google-play-developer-console-if-both-are-no).

I want to integrate billing into my app but therefore I need to link the projects

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'd have to add `def@gmail.com` as user on the Play Console first (the same project).

Similarly, it might also be possible to add `abc@gmail.com` to the GCP project.

App Linking requires twice the same ID, no matter how it is being accomplished.

Comment: I now gave admin and owner rights on both ends. No idea which permission are required but it worked now. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

In my case I was using a service account, and trying to use this service account from within appcenter.ms in order to publish to play store from there.
I tried two things:

1. On google cloud console I gave the service account, which was
   already owner, the service account admin role.
2. Second from the play console, I invited as admin the email added
   automatically on the service account in google cloud console, to somehow
   link play console with cloud console.

Not sure which of the above did it, but after completing the above 2 steps I was able to link appcenter.ms to google play store. Hope this helps anyone I had trouble for some time with it especially now that the google play console no longer has the api access page mentioned in the documentation.